# Image extension validator

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

I am new to regular extension, I am using following code to validate image extension, its giving me wrong output when I pass image name with space. Please provide me solution.

```
public class Test
{
    private static final String IMAGE_PATTERN   = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";
    private Pattern             pattern;
    private Matcher             matcher;

    public Test()
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);
    }

    /**
     * Validate image with regular expression
     * 
     * @param image
     *            image for validation
     * @return true valid image, false invalid image
     */
    public boolean validate(final String image)
    {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(image);
        return matcher.matches();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test s = new Test();
        System.out.println(s.validate("four row Cylindrical Roller Bearing2.jpg"));
    }
}
```

It gives Output as false.

Comment: Where did you get this regex? Do you know what `[^\\s]` means?

Comment: Vour Regex is wrong and ways to complicated. Try `IMAGE_PATTERN = "^.+\\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$";`

Comment: @blafasel `matches` method checks if regex matches entire string so we don't need `^` and `$` anchors. Also adding `(?i)` is good thing because it lets regex match uppercase characters in extension like `JPG` extension (rest of uppercase was already included in `[^\\s]`).

Comment: @Pshemo You are completely write (+1). So the perfect solution is `IMAGE_PATTERN = ".+\\.(?i:jpg|png|gif|bmp)";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `[^\\s]+` at the beginning of your pattern with `.+`. Since `[^\\s]+` explicitly matches only non-whitespace characters, the expression will fail for any file name containing a whitespace.

Comment: Thanks allot..!! :)
Its giving true when i pass .jpg name as image name i.e without name only dot(.)extenson as image name, what further changes should i do?